# Insert performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I am having trouble with Posgresql insert performance.  There are 2 tables, `documents` and `words`, where `documents` is essentially a mapping from an external path to a surrogate  id, which is foreign keyed onto the doc column in the  `words` table.

The tables are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
     id         serial,
     title    text
);
ALTER TABLE documents ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE words (
     id         serial,
     doc    integer,
     location    integer,
     sentence  text,
     sentence_location integer
);
ALTER TABLE words ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE words ADD CONSTRAINT doc_fk FOREIGN KEY (doc) REFERENCES documents (id);
```

There are about 40k rows in the `documents` table, and 1.5m in the `words` table.  The problem is that when inserting a row in the `words` table, the insert is taking about a second, for example

```
INSERT INTO words (doc, location, sentence, sentence_location) 
VALUES (1001, 52, “hello world”, 5);
```

I’m assuming that the issue is that the large number of rows in the `words` table makes updating the index very slow.  Is there a way to improve this situation?

NB this is not a one off batch insert, so tearing down the index, and rebuilding is not a solution.

Comment: An insert of 1 row takes 1 second? Or an insert of many rows? Please show us a sample `INSERT` statement. Also add your postgres version.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Ok, I have added an example insert.  The problem is that an insert of a single row is taking about that time.

Comment: Are there are other indexes on the table? I only see the 2 primary keys. Not that that would explain such a slow insert in a table. A million rows is small in today's machine sizes. How do you do the inserts? Perhaps it's a connection issue. Can you affirm that the insert is slow if you do it through psql?

Comment: Does it stay the same after adding an index on `words (doc)`?